# Can this special case of a Theorem by Bonsall be generalised slightly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

When choosing $\Delta := \mathbb N$, $M_1 = M_2 = 1$ in Theorem 1 in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b687/3258fd44857692439204196b36de0396680f.pdf) by F.F. Bonsall, we obtain the following variant:

**Theorem 1 (Variant).**
Let $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ be a Banach space, $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \subset X$ such that $\| u_k \| \le 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$ and
$$
\sup_{k \in \mathbb N} | \psi(u_k) | = \| \psi \|_{X^*}
$$
for all $\psi \in X^*$ and for $f \in X$
$$
L(f, (u_k)_{k \in \mathbb N})
:= \left\{ \lambda = (\lambda_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \in \ell^1(\mathbb N): f = \sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \lambda_k u_k \right\}.
$$

> Then $L(f, u) \ne \emptyset$ for all $f \in X$ and $\| f \| = \inf_{\lambda \in L(f, u)} \| \lambda \|_{\ell^1(\mathbb N)}$.

**My Question.**
If I take a set $E \subset X$ such that $\| u \| \le 1$ for all $u \in E$ and $\sup_{u \in E} | \psi(u) | = \| \psi \|_{X^*}$ for all $\psi \in X^*$ instead of the sequence $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \subset X$ with those properties, can I still conclude that the set
$$
L(f, E) := \left\{ \lambda = (\lambda_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \in \ell^1(\mathbb N): f = \sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \lambda_k u_k, \ (u_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \subset E \right\}
$$
is nonempty for each $f \in X$ and that $\| f \| = \inf_{c \in L(f, E)} \| c \|_{\ell^1(\mathbb N)}$?

I hope this is true as one can write $E$ as a subset of the union of all sequences $u$ considered in the variant of theorem 1.

**My try.**
*Nonemptyness:*
By the properties of $E$, there is a sequence $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \subset E$ fulfilling the conditions in the variant of Theorem 1.
Let $f \in X$.
There there exists a $\tilde{\lambda} \in L(f, (u_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}) \subset L(f, E)$ by the variant of Theorem 1, so $L(f, E) \ne \emptyset$.

Is the norm condition true, as well?

*Note.*
I am aware that the result I seek is true, as it is proven in [this](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/42/1/9/1545093?redirectedFrom=fulltext) later paper by the same author. But that proof is rather cumbersome and unintuitive, as it strictly avoids the use of Banach's closed range theorem (because later in the paper the author demonstrates an easy proof of the closed range theorem with the help of the above result). The proof in the first paper uses the closed range theorem and thus is much shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$
|\psi(u)| \le \|u\|_X \, \|\psi\|_{X^*}
$$
you still have $\sup_{u \in E} |\psi(u)| = \|\psi\|_{X^*}$,
i.e. there is no difference in this assumption.

As you said, there is a sequence $(u_k) \subset E$ such that theorem 1 can be applied. Hence,
$$
\inf_{c \in L(f,E)} \|c\| \le \inf_{c \in L(f, (u_k))} \|c\| = \|f\|.$$
To the contrary,
for every $c \in L(f,E)$, there is a sequence $(u_k^{(c)}) \subset E$ (take the above sequence amended by the terms appearing in the statement of $c \in L(f,E)$), such that
it satisfies the assumptions of theorem 1 and
$c \in L(f,(u_k^{(c)}))$.
Hence,
$$\|c\| \ge \inf_{d \in L(f,(u_k^{(c)}))}\|d\| = \|f\|.$$

This shows the norm statement.

Comment: Another question: the first paper actually requires $\sup_{u \in E} | \psi(u) | \ge \| \psi \|$, but that is equivalent to equality as $\| u \| \le 1$ for all $u \in E$ and thus $\sup_{u \in E} | \psi(u) | \le \| \psi \|$, right?

Comment: Yes. This is the first argument in my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "terms appearing in the statement of $c \in L(f, E)$"?

Comment: 1. Yes, we have equality here. 2. $c \in L(f,E)$ mean that there is a sequence $(u_k^{(c)})$ with $f = \sum c_k u_k^{(c)}$. I am referring to this sequence.